# right side of fixed div overflow its parent

Tags: html, css, position, fixed

I am trying to put a `position:fixed` div inside an another div. I want a fixed div which has a `width:100%;` so it will be great for mobile and desktop at the same time.

Here is my [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eLzwvzb3/)

SF wants some code:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="item">This div is good div</div>
  <div id="fixed">Right side of this div overflow its parent!!! </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `calc()` method to adapt the viewport size. Just subtract right and left margin from the 100%:

**Edit**: I added a min-height to the body to see the "fixed-effect" on scrolling

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 1000px;
}
#container {
  margin: 10px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
#item {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
#item {
  background: blue;
}
#fixed {
  height: 50px;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  background: green;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="item">Normal div</div>
  <div id="fixed">Fixed div</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

An element with `position: fixed;` ignores the parent size because it is relative only to the viewport:

[MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Fixed_positioning)

> Fixed positioning is similar to absolute positioning, with the exception that the element's containing block is the viewport.

You can:

1. Try giving it `position: absolute;` and set the container to `position: relative;`.
2. Use `position: fixed;` and set the size explicitly.

Comment: but it does not ignore parents  left margin

Comment: It is placed in the document by its static position and then it is taken out of the normal document flow